# Problem with absolute path and [ngerman] babel?

Tags: errors, babel, input, document-configuration, underscore

I want to get rid of relative paths and defines a new command which point to the root folder of my project:

```
\providecommand{\myPath}{C:/Users/xxx/Google Drive/WS_1819/Bachelorarbeit/_new/}
```

However, when i try to use this absoulte path like so:

```
\input{"C:/Users/xxx/Google Drive/WS_1819/Bachelorarbeit/_new/_text/text.tex"}
```

I receive this error:

```
! Argument of \language@active@arg" has an extra }.
```

As my MWE worked with this my intention was that some packages I used in the project causes this. After trying around I found out that

```
\usepackage[ngerman]babel
```

causes this. Maybe because of the underlines in the path? Anyone an easy solution how I can solve this without renaming the whole paths in my project?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[space]{grffile}

\begin{document}
%\input{preamble/packages.tex}
\input{"C:/Users/Sebastian/Google Drive/pathtest/preamble/packages.tex"}
\end{document}
```

I really dont know how to solve this issue :/

Comment: it will be the double quote `"` which german uses as a shorthand, but you don't need them in the input, so you can just remove them. But normally it's best to avoid absolute paths, they just make the document non-portable (or as there is a space in `google drive` use `\string"` at each end rather than `"`

Comment: thanks.yeah i knew absoulte paths are not great, but using subimports before did not work riether as I used them inn nested ways and the somehow get confused. so i decided to use a absoulte path just to the root to my project.

Comment: when deleting the " I receive the error: missing $ inserted

Comment: Actually I can't guess why you would need that (or subimports) but as you have provided not example hard to guess, but anyway `\string"` should work, or locally use the babel command to turn off the shorthand

Comment: yes sorry I had not noticed the space in your path, so you do need `"`

Comment: You really should avoid such absolute pathes. They indicate that something is wrong in your general project setup.

Comment: i added a MWE.. @David what do you mean with using \string?

Comment: I meant `\input{\string"C:/Users/Sebastian/Google Drive/pathtest/preamble/packages.tex\string"}` but I would never use such a path in a document, why not just `\input{packages}` ???